# How to create custom tags for HTML

Tags: html, tags

How can I create custom meta tags for HTML, with special attributes and behavior?

Comment: Dunno if you can do it in pure HTML but maybe you can use XHTML, the XML part has custom tags made by you

Answer (score 56, accepted):

There's an interesting and in depth article from HTML5Rocks.com on how to work with custom elements : [Custom Elements: Defining New Elements in HTML](https://web.archive.org/web/20140118032429/http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/)

Here's an excerpt from the article on how to do it.

### Instantiating elements

The common techniques of creating elements still apply to custom elements. As with any standard element, they can be declared in HTML or created in DOM using JavaScript.
Instantiating custom tags

**Declare them:**

```html
<x-foo></x-foo>
```

**Create DOM in JS:**

```js
var xFoo = document.createElement('x-foo');
xFoo.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    alert('Thanks!');
});
```

**Use the new operator:**

```js
var xFoo = new XFoo();
document.body.appendChild(xFoo);
```

Comment: Worth noting is that this is the correct way to do it in terms of standards and browser support. `foo-bar` should always be used for custom tag names (hyphen required, `x-` is common), and `data-foo` should always be used for custom attributes (`data-` required). Browsers may or may not handle arbitrary tags like `foo` well. Generally they don't cause errors, but it's completely non-standard and may cause issues in some situations. Also note that non-HTML5 content should use a non-strict doctype when doing this. JS can be used to skirt the "data-" attribute restriction, but it's clunky.

Comment: Updated specification for Custom Elements v1: Reusable Web Components https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/customelements

Answer (score 64):

Depending on what you mean by "special attributes and behavior," you can "create" custom HTML tags right now. The following shows up in all browsers, and even works with the various JavaScript methods:

```
<my-book data-pages="400" data-author="Nietzsche">The Wanderer and His Shadow</my-book>
```

There are just a couple of things you have to keep in mind:

0. **Hyphenation**! Custom elements should consist of at least one `-` like `my-book` or `app-menu` or `header-title`, etc. Just, don't use `data-*` since it's reserved for *data- attributes*.
1. All custom elements have a display of `inline` by default. You can change that with CSS or JavaScript, however.
2. Internet Explorer does not recognize any of these elements unless you **first** "create" them with JavaScript:

   ```
    document.createElement('my-book');
   ```

So you have to do that *before* you can use them in your CSS, HTML, or JavaScript.

Comment: I was gonna make a <hasjs> tag that was hidden for js-disabled users, but now I have to register it with JavaScript first. Guess I'll have to stick with <div class="hasjs">.

Comment: @apokaliptis for js disabled problem perhaps you can use <noscript>your normal html for no js enabled browsers</noscript>

Comment: It would be nice to include some references for this answer.

Answer (score 21):

All you really have to do is define CSS content for that tag.

Example:

```css
mytag {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

And now the *mytag* is your own bold:

```html
<mytag>This text is in bold</mytag>
```

Comment: I know this at least works for Google Chrome 47

Comment: Sure this works in chrome 47, but it's not advised as it is just invalid HTML. Chrome can handle a wide range of invalid code, and while it does *work*, you really shouldn't be leaning on that too much as its behaviour in other browsers can be completely arbitrary.

Comment: @vrugtehagel That sounds an awful lot like IE in the 90's and 2000's. Deviating from standards and make people rely on the quirks. "You must use IE" => "You must use Chrome". Not a good thing.

Comment: @user3342816 "That sounds an awful lot like IE in the 90's and 2000's." So far, Chrome is not behaving that way that I have seen. That invalid HTML is forced to work is part of the fundamental design of the Web, and is true in all browsers.

Comment: as others have pointed out you should uwe kebab case with at least one - . Reason: who knows what new tags the standard will come up with and break your shiny website by givin `mytag` a whole different meaning. Standard tags never will contain a `-`.

Answer (score 12):

There is now an emerging [W3C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web_Consortium) standard specification, called [Web Component Custom Elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements), that enables developers to create their own custom HTML elements and register them with the browser parser.

Mozilla has developed a library, named X-Tag, that makes the process of creating and working with custom elements super easy, check it out: [X-Tags.org](http://www.x-tags.org)

Answer (score 4):

There is also a version which is *only* supported in Chrome 54 and [Opera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29).

Example:

```javascript
class BasicElement extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        this.textContent = 'Just a basic custom element.';
    }
}
customElements.define('basic-element', BasicElement);
```

You can learn more about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define).

Comment: Now it works in Safari too: http://www.caniuse.com/#search=custom%20elements%20v1

Comment: Good to know mate thanks.

Comment: And on firefox, too

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom HTML tags with following steps:

Step 1 - Register a new *element*. Custom elements are created using document.registerElement():

```javascript
var XFoo = document.registerElement('x-foo', {
    prototype: Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype)
});
```

The second argument in registerElement is optional object which describes the element's prototype.

Step 2 - Instantiating custom tags

There are several ways to do so:

Declare them:

```html
<x-foo></x-foo>
```

Create DOM in JavaScript:

```javascript
var xFoo = document.createElement('x-foo');
xFoo.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    alert('Thanks!');
});
```

Use the new operator:

```javascript
var xFoo = new XFoo();
```

Step 3 - Attach the newly created element with *document*

```javascript
document.body.appendChild(new XFoo());
```

Complete example:

```javascript
var XFooProto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

// 1. Give x-foo a foo() method.
XFooProto.foo = function() {
  alert('foo() called');
};

// 2. Define a property read-only "bar".
Object.defineProperty(XFooProto, "bar", {value: 5});

// 3. Register x-foo's definition.
var XFoo = document.registerElement('x-foo', {prototype: XFooProto});

// 4. Instantiate an x-foo.
var xfoo = document.createElement('x-foo');

// 5. Add it to the page.
document.body.appendChild(xfoo);
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me.

Comment: TypeError: document.registerElement is not a function. (In 'document.registerElement()', 'document.registerElement' is undefined)

Comment: Warning: document.registerElement() is deprecated in favor of customElements.define(). Source [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/registerElement)