# Custom Tags in HTML

Tags: html, tags

The following doesn't work:

```
<landing id="showcase">
<h1>Welcome to the Beach</h1>
<p>Dies ist eine kleine test seite mit einer landing page</p>
<a href="#" class="button">Welcome</a>
```

When I substituted the tag-name from "landing" to "header", it worked. But why does it work with the `header` as tag name?
I am not sure if I can define any tag-name I want to. Is it that an attribute works only with global tag-names?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create custom tags for html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682943/how-to-create-custom-tags-for-html)

Comment: What do you mean by saying that with `header` “it worked”? There is nothing that a browser is required to do with `header` tags (except parse them); the same applies to tags you just make up.

Comment: Need to insert closing tag of landing as </landing> is missing.. Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

The reason header works is it's a semantic HTML class.  I'd recommend reading the link below.

[semantic HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp)

Comment: The reason `header` works isn't that it's a *semantic* HTML element specifically, but simply that it's a [known HTML element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element). `div` isn't a semantic element, but it would work too in this case.

Comment: Thank you sir for you help. Browsed w3schools for that one since I had already read up on it before, but didn't really know what to "look" for.
Cheers from Switzerland

Answer (score 0):

Well yes, custom element are possible provided that:

Element names are lowercase and begin with x-

In your case, x-landing id="showcase"

Also, don't forget a closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

`landing` is not a known tag for developers or browsers so it does not get interpreted in the browser (i.e. converted into a human-readable element), while `header` is an HTML5 semantic element and is known to browsers (at least modern ones).

> The HTML `header` element represents a group of introductory or navigational aids. It may contain some heading elements but also other elements like a logo, a search form, and so on.

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header)

Answer (score 0):

The only valid names of elements you can use are the ones in this list: [HTML element reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element)

[`<header>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header) is in that list, so it is valid. `<landing>` is not on that list, so it is invalid.

You shouldn't just make up a name for an element. You should either use an existing element that matches its meaning, such as [`<p>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) for a paragraph or [`<header>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header) for the header of a page, or you should use one of the generic elements [`<div>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) (a [block-level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)) or [`<span>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) (an [inline element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements)) which have no semantic meaning.

You can add a [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) or [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) attribute to any element if you want to identify it later from JavaScript or CSS code.

Comment: Thank you a thousand for your quick explanation.
Have a good morning (or evening).