# Custom Tag for just Decorations purpose using only CSS

Tags: html, css

i as just thinking is possible to create custom tag with CSS only.that customs tag might not be ought to have attributes.

```
<mytag>blah blah blah</myTag>
```

CSS:

```
myTag{
font-family:"cybertron";
font-size:2.5em;
font-weight:blod;
color:blue;
}
```

Comment: `<span class="mytag">` job done.

Comment: i tried it, the way i wrote in question with    <h0></h0>    .And IT WORKED! .I used this method to avoid using class="" over and over agin

Comment: although it's same as using class="#" . But it's more convinient if you using it over and over agin

Comment: `But it's more convinient if you using it over and over again` --> i don't agree, class are created to used over and over again ... then don't forget the semantic part, custom tag has no meaning unlike know tags (p, h*,section, etc)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create custom tags for html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682943/how-to-create-custom-tags-for-html)

Comment: Well, that uses Javascript while this with CSS only.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. I think the most important css attribute to set is display, the rest works just as regular well-known HTML tags.

```css
mytag {
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>Something above</div>
<mytag>My tag text</mytag>
<div>Something below</div>
```

Comment: display attribute is optional to add,maybe..if the tag is to used inline then no need to change, if it's ought be used as like div . then,block is optional ,<div> is just like we can say  <br><span>BlahBlahBlah</span><br>