# How to create a custom HTML tag that changes the text color of everything inside it?

Tags: html, css, colors

So basically I want to make a tag, such as , that when placed into an h element or a p element will turn the text inside the color red.

```
<p>Hello <r>World!</r> I'm a sentence!</p>
```

such as that. the "World!" would be red, while the rest would be the default text color that I set for the p tag. I know HTML and CSS.

Comment: `r` isn't a valid custom element name, and this sort of job is best left to `em` or some other standard element with semantics that describe *why* you want the colour to change (which is better food for search engines and screen readers).

Comment: try look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5682943/2996989)

Comment: after defining the element, define css for that element.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this attribute to your HTML tags as needed:

```html
style="color:red;"
```

**Note that this is not the best practice.** The best way to do this is to create a class that sets all of its elements' `style` properties to `red`. Also, instead of using a custom element like `r`, try using a `span` (thanks to Bryan in the comments). For example:

CSS:

```css
.redText {
    color:red;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<p>Hello <span class="redText">World!</span> I'm a sentence!</p>
```

Comment: I would also recommend a span over a "custom" HTML element.

Comment: If this helped you out, I would appreciate it if you marked my answer as the accepted solution and upvoted the post. Thank you for posting.