# Initialisation of Custom Elements Inside Document Fragment

Tags: javascript, html, custom-element, documentfragment, html-templates

Consider this HTML `template` with two flat `x-element`s and one nested.

```html
<template id="fooTemplate">
  <x-element>Enter your text node here.</x-element>
  <x-element>
    <x-element>Hello, World?</x-element>
  </x-element>
</template>
```

---

How to initialise (fire constructor) all custom elements in cloned from `fooTemplate` document fragment without appending it to DOM, neither by extending built-in elements with `is="x-element"`; either entire fragment.

```
class XElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() { super(); }
  foo() { console.log( this ); }
} customElements.define( 'x-element', XElement );

const uselessf = function( temp ) {
  const frag = window[ temp ].content.cloneNode( true );

  /* Your magic code goes here:
  */ do_black_magic( frag );

  for (const e of  frag.querySelectorAll('x-element') )
    e.foo(); // This should work.

  return frag;
};

window['someNode'].appendChild( uselessf('fooTemplate') );
```

*Note that script executes with `defer` attribute.*

Comment: Maybe I should somehow upcast `HTMLElement` to `XElement`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can initialise template with this arrow function:

```
const initTemplate = temp =>
  document.createRange().createContextualFragment( temp.innerHTML );

const frag = initTemplate( window['someTemplate'] );
```

Or with this method defined on `template` prototype (I prefer this way):

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLTemplateElement.prototype, 'initialise', {
  enumerable: false,
  value() {
    return document.createRange().createContextualFragment( this.innerHTML );
  }
});

const frag = window['someTemplate'].initialise();
```

In any case in result this code will work fine:

```
for (const elem of  frag.querySelectorAll('x-element') )
  elem.foo();

window['someNode'].appendChild( frag );
```

---

*I'm not sure if these methods are the most effective way to initialise custom elements in template.*

*Also note that there is no need for cloning template.*

Comment: @LogicalBranch in first link Eric uses `document.registerElement` which is deprecated and in last link nothing about custom elements in templates.

Comment: What I was about: [first link](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/), [second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682943/how-to-create-custom-tags-for-html)

Comment: `document.createRange().createContextualFragment( temp.innerHTML );` will actually create a copy of the template contents/html. The reason this works is because the copy uses the global document as the context/ownerDocument.

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR:**

Use `document.importNode(template.content, true);` instead of `template.content.cloneNode(true);`
[Read more about document.importNode() here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/importNode)

**Explanation:**

Since the custom element is created in a different document/context (the [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) of the template) it doesn't know about the custom elements definition in the root/global document. You can get the document an element belongs to by reading the `Node.ownerDocument` property ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/ownerDocument)) which in this case will be different to the `window.document` element.

This being said you need to create the custom element in the context of the global document in order to "apply" the custom element. This can be done by calling `document.importNode(node, [true])` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/importNode)) which works like `node.cloneNode([true])`, but creates a copy of the element in the global document context.

Alternatively you can also use `document.adoptNode(node)` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/adoptNode)) to first adopt the DocumentFragment to the global document and then create copies of it via `node.cloneNode([true])`. Note though if you use `adoptNode()` on an HTML element it will be removed from its original document.

**Illustrative Example Code:**

```js
class XElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() { super(); console.log("Custom Element Constructed") }
}
customElements.define( 'x-element', XElement );

const externalFragment = fooTemplate.content;

console.log(
  "Is ownerDocument equal?",
  externalFragment.ownerDocument === document
);

console.log("import start");

const importedFragment = document.importNode(externalFragment, true);

console.log("import end");

console.log(
  "Is ownerDocument equal?",
  importedFragment.ownerDocument === document
);
```

```html
<template id="fooTemplate">
  <x-element>Hello, World?</x-element>
</template>
```

**Note:** Appending an element from one document to another document forces an [implicit adoption of the node](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-dom/2010JulSep/0111.html). That's why appending the element to the global DOM works in this case.

Comment: This is the correct answer!!!

Something you do not want to add the document fragment to the DOM prior to manipulation or query. 

- You want to be able to manipulate without bubbling up events. 
- You want to query the document fragment in a silo rather than querying in the context of the whole doc. 

document.importNode(MY_COMPONENT_TEMPLATE, true) allows to have light DocumentFragment templates, and "activate" their content on clone. Best of both world!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Impressive, thank you! how did you learn all this? I could not garner this much understanding from reading the MDN articles about all of these functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the "createContextualFragment" hack from the previous answer by simply adding the template clone to the `document` immediately *before* processing it.

Assuming we have these two variables defined...

```
const containerEl = document.querySelector('div.my-container')
const templateEl = document.querySelector('#fooTemplate')
```

...instead of doing this (where `frag` contains uninitialised custom elements)...

```
const frag = templateEl.content.cloneNode(true)
manipulateTemplateContent(frag)
containerEl.appendChild(frag)
```

...append the template clone to the document *first*, then manipulate it. The user won't notice any difference - it's all synchronous code executed within the same frame.

```
const frag = templateEl.content.cloneNode(true)
containerEl.appendChild(frag)
manipulateTemplateContent(containerEl)
```