# This is a weird html tag

Tags: javascript, html

I was looking in a website's code with the inspect tool. And I saw a tag I've never seen before.

```
<gblockquote></gblockquote>
```

I've heard of a blockquote, but never a gblockquote.

There was nothing in between the tags. Just that.

I tried looking it up, but nothing relevant came up. Does someone know what it is?

(Full Element)

```
<p>
   <img src="http://www.scottgames.com/Montgomery.jpg" 
      <p="">
         <font size="7">
            <gblockquote></gblockquote>
         </font>
</p>
```

The guy's syntax was horrible, but the gblockquote interests me

Comment: techncally you can use any kind of custom element you want even `<foo>` can be a valid element if you correctly set the CSS

Comment: Probably [a custom HTML tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682943/how-to-create-custom-tags-for-html)

Comment: I guess [this is a better link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802687/is-there-a-way-to-create-your-own-html-tag-in-html5)

Answer (score 1):

`<gblockquote>` was defined by CSS code.
Example: This CSS code defines a new HTML tag called `<myhtmltag>`.

```
myhtmltag {
   color: red; /*change the text color to red.*/
   font-size: 48px; /*change the font size to 48px.*/
}
```

And now let's use it:

```
<myhtmltag>This is a BIG and RED text!</myhtmltag>
```

Here's a code snippet:

```css
myhtmltag {
  color: red; /*change the text color to red.*/
  font-size: 48px; /*change the font size to 48px.*/
}
```

```html
<myhtmltag>This is a BIG and RED text!</myhtmltag>
```

Comment: Where did you find this in the source?