# Dynamically create column and row in HTML

Tags: html

I have data structure like this. and 
`<param1>` could be repeating . We can have multiple value for  param1

```
<param>
  <param1>
    <name>
    <value>
  </param1>
  <param1>
    <name1>
    <value1>
    </param1>
</param>
I want to display in html dynamically like this(like column row ).  How can we do it ???        

name     name1
value    value1

Can someone suggest how to do it . I am new to this area
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution should be:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
        param-list {
        font-size : 20px;
        display:inline-block;
        border:1px solid gray;
        }
        param-list > *{
        font-size : 20px;
        display:block;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <param-list>
            <my-name></my-name>
            <my-value></my-value>
        </param-list>
        <param-list>
            <my-name1></my-name1>
            <my-value1></my-value1>
        </param-list>
        <script>
            class ParamList extends HTMLElement {
              connectedCallback() {
                 this.children;
              }
            }
            customElements.define('param-list', ParamList); 
            
            class Name extends HTMLElement {
              connectedCallback() {
                this.innerHTML = `name`;
              }
            }
            customElements.define('my-name', Name);
            
            class Name1 extends HTMLElement {
              connectedCallback() {
                this.innerHTML = `name1`;
              }
            }
            customElements.define('my-name1', Name1);
            class Value extends HTMLElement {
              connectedCallback() {
                this.innerHTML = `value`;
              }
            }
            customElements.define('my-value', Value);
            
            class Value1 extends HTMLElement {
              connectedCallback() {
                this.innerHTML = `value1`;
              }
            }
            customElements.define('my-value1', Value1);
             
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Live at [custom-element](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GFAUNIVN30TE)

ref:

- https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/
- [How to create custom tags for html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682943/how-to-create-custom-tags-for-html)
- https://dev.to/jfbrennan/custom-html-tags-4788
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements

Comment: Thanks but the data coming from a source and I dont want to manually define it rather pass it as a variable so that it can take at run time as it comes