# Spoiler tag with details+summary

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a custom element in HTML with javascript. It's a `spoiler` tag, and uses `details` and `summary`.

I want to be able to do this:

```html
<spoiler summary="Spoiler">
Spoiler text
</spoiler>
```

which would expand to this:

```html
<details><summary>Spoiler</summary>
Spoiler text
</details>
```

I've tried this:

```js
function create_tag(tagName, fn) {
  document.getElementsByTagName(tagName).map(fn);
}

function spoiler(elem) {
  if (elem.attributes.summary) {
    elem.innerHTML =
      "<details><summary>" +
      elem.attributes.summary +
      "</summary>" +
      elem.innerHTML +
      "</details>";
  }
}

create_tag("spoiler", spoiler);
```

But it does nothing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682943/how-to-create-custom-tags-for-html this may help u

Answer (score 1):

'getElementsByTagName' returns a 'NodeList'. You need to transform it to an array in orden to apply the map funcion (which is a function in the Array class, but not in the NodeList class). You can do it using `Array.from(yourNodeList)`.

Second, check the line `elem.attributes.summary.nodeValue +` .

```js
function create_tag(tagName, fn) {
  console.log(document.getElementsByTagName(tagName)); // Check this output
  // You need to convert the object to an array
  spoiler(Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName(tagName)).map(fn));
}

function spoiler(elem) {
  // Added some extra checks
  if (elem && elem.attributes && elem.attributes.summary) {
    console.log(elem.attributes) // Check this output
    elem.innerHTML =
      "<details><summary>" +
      elem.attributes.summary.nodeValue +
      "</summary>" +
      elem.innerHTML +
      "</details>";
  }
}

create_tag("spoiler", spoiler);
```

```html
<spoiler summary="Spoiler">Spoiler text 1</spoiler>
<spoiler summary="Spoiler">Spoiler text 2</spoiler>
<spoiler summary="Spoiler">Spoiler text 3</spoiler>
```