# Create custom tags html

Tags: html, css

I want to create custom tags in html to do some sort of thing like is there any way to turn html and css divs into tags?

```css
.me {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="me"></div><br>
<p>Make the above div a "redbox" tag or something</p>
```

Comment: Duplicate.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682943/how-to-create-custom-tags-for-html

Comment: Did you google first?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create custom tags for html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682943/how-to-create-custom-tags-for-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You can so something like this:

```css
redbox {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<redbox></redbox>
<!-- OR -->
<redbox />
```

#### You can pass attributes like this:

```css
redbox {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

redbox[center] {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<redbox center/>
```

**OR**

```css
redbox {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

redbox[align="center"] {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<redbox align="center" />
```

Comment: is there any way I could pass parameters so it looks like `<redbox center/>`

Comment: @CrimsonX I have updated the answer, is that what you wanted right?

Comment: Yes this does help.