# Custom HTML element that behaves like the built-in <div> elment

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, custom-element

I want to create a custom HTML element that behaves exactly like the built-in `<div>` element. I'm trying to prevent a `<div>` soup. I would for example want to have a `<currency-list>` element. This element should behave exactly like the `<div>` element. The only difference is the name. How can I achieve this?

Thanks,
Yosemite

Comment: are you aware there are [other tags beside `<div>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#sectioning_content)?

Comment: What is the question here? We know (vaguely) what you want; whats stopping you?

Comment: There are other tags apart from div. Like `<main></main>` or `<article></article>` and yes they do help organize your code and also help with SEO.  Have a look here https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp

Comment: I am aware that there are other tags apart from the ```<div>``` element.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682943/how-to-create-custom-tags-for-html I think this should help if this is what you mean.

Comment: [MDN:Using_custom_elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements)

Comment: HTML kind of has enough semantic elements, so unless you can explain what problem you're really trying to solve (because "div soup" is principally caused by creating completely unnecessary tags, not by the fact that they're divs) this feels like an XY problem, where you're asking for help in addressing a symptom, rather than the problem itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a DIV ([HTMLDivElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDivElement)) is a `block` element.

But you don't even need a *defined* Custom Element/Web Component to make a `block` element

```js
customElements.define("currency-list", class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

```css
another-list {
  display: block;
}

body>*:defined {
  background: green;
  color: beige;
}

body>*:not(:defined) {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
Line 1
<currency-list>Hello Web Component</currency-list>
Line 3
<div>Line 4</div>
Line 5
<another-list onclick="alert(this.constructor.name)">Line 6</another-list>
Line 7
```

[image]

##### Notes:

- `<currency-list>` is an ["Autonomous Custom Element"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements#autonomous_custom_elements) (`extends HTMLElement`)
- You can *extend* [`HTMLDivElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDivElement) in Chromium and FireFox, but Apple has stated they will never implement ["Customized Built-In Elements"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements#customized_built-in_elements)
  From: https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/509

[image]

- `<another-list>` is an [HTMLUnknownElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLUnknownElement); nothing wrong with using it, its `constructor` ***is*** an `HTMLElement`, so can do everything an `HTMLElement` can do.
  For more on the value of Unknown Elements see [my Dev.to post](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/web-components-using-unknownhtmlelements-for-better-semantic-html-5d8c)
- You can set any CSS `display` value on a DIV, you can't on your own Elements, as it will destroy the `display:block` setting.

PS. tag your SO questions `web-component` and/or `custom-element`