# can use html img tag as custom tag like <image src="">?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
image {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<image src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow">
</body>
</html>
```

border not applying in HTML custom image tag. is possible to fix?

border not applying in HTML custom image tag. is possible to fix? i want image tag with border not changing <img> tag.

Comment: Why don't you just create an `img` tag and add a specific class, e.g. `border`, to it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create custom tags for HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682943/how-to-create-custom-tags-for-html)

Comment: But i think custom tags wont show image

Comment: That's correct, one would need to implement all behaviors/attributes

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a custom tag like  instead of  for your image element and set a custom attribute for the source, you can do so using HTML5's Custom Elements (also known as Web Components). Custom Elements allow you to define your own custom HTML elements with custom behavior. Here's how you can create a custom  element:

```js
class CustomImage extends HTMLElement {
      constructor() {
          super();
      }

      connectedCallback() {
          // Get the value of the custom-src attribute
          const customSrc = this.getAttribute('custom-src');
          if (customSrc) {
              // Create an <img> element
              const img = document.createElement('img');
              img.src = customSrc;

              // Append the <img> element to the custom <image> element
              this.appendChild(img);
          }
      }
  }

  customElements.define('custom-image', CustomImage);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Custom Image Element Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Use the custom <image> element with a custom-src attribute -->
    <custom-image custom-src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg"></custom-image>
</body>
</html>
```

In this code, we define a **CustomImage** class that extends HTMLElement. When a custom-image element is added to the **DOM**, the **connectedCallback** method is called. Inside this method, we read the custom-src attribute and create an  element with the specified source. We then append the  element to the custom  element.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an id that way you won't change the border of all img, just the one with the id.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #image {
      border: 5px solid red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <img id="image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why use an id over a class?

Comment: You usually use id to identify a single instance of an element. I would use class if i need more than one image with a red border.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wants to do this you can with web components custom element

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_custom_elements

This will attach the real `img` tag to the shadow root.

Because the `img` tag is in shadow root you cannot modify the style from outside and need to change the style from the `CustomImage` class

But because web component tag name must include `-` you can't use `image` as the tag name instead use `custom-image`

```js
class CustomImage extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.attachShadow({
      mode: "open"
    });

    const src = this.getAttribute('src') ?? '';
    const alt = this.getAttribute('alt') ?? '';

    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = src;
    img.alt = alt;

    const style = document.createElement("style");
    style.textContent = `img { border: 5px red solid; }`;

    this.shadowRoot.append(style, img);
  }

}

customElements.define("custom-image", CustomImage);
```

```html
<custom-image src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow">
```